# JSP does not insert my data into database

Tags: jsp, jdbc

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Blob"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.BatchUpdateException"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%> 

<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">

    <title>My JSP 'p.jsp' starting page</title>

 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
 <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
 <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
 <!--
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 -->

  </head>

  <body>
    <% 

int activityId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("activityId"));
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String activityType = request.getParameter("activityType");
int parentId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parentId"));
String description = request.getParameter("description");
%>
 <%
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pol","root","1234");
 Statement st=conn.createStatement();

String queryString = "INSERT INTO activity(activityId,name,activityType,parentId,description)" + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

 pstatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);

pstatement.setInt(1, activityId);
pstatement.setString(2, name);
pstatement.setString(3, activityType);
pstatement.setInt(4, parentId);
pstatement.setString(5, description);

 }
catch (Exception ex) {
   out.println("Unable to connect to batabase.");
}

finally {
pstatement.close();
conn.close();

}

%>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens? Does it fail with some error message?

Comment: He would never be able to determine it, since he's suppressing the `ex` in the catch block instead of printing/throwing it. Regardless, Rup has already nailed it down. He's never giving the command to execute the query. @lehkni: this might be homework/schoolwork, but this piece of code is considered extremely bad practice in real world. Lesson 1: do not use *scriptlets*, but real Java classes.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you probably want to move the database code into another class and call that class instead of having DB code on the JSP. This will provide better reusability and make the code easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: @BalusC: How is being homework an excuse for being bad? Aren't they supposed to teach you to write maintainable code at school...?

Comment: @Matti: You can't stop them from doing it :/

Answer (score 2):

You never call `pstatement.executeUpdate();` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing execute update: `ps.executeUpdate();`